# Passing in a large string of Guids

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2005, query-optimization

I have a stored procedure with 2 issues.

1. It has 40 parameters.  I know the first comment is going to be to re-design my stored procedure so it doesn't have 40 parameters.  However, this is a search form with a big criteria section.  So the user is specifying up to 40 different criteria for the search.  Then we're passing in these values each as a parameter.  Right now I have a 40 parameter sproc.  Would it be more efficient to pass these in as an XML parameter and parse it inside or a table parameter (we are still running SQL 2k5 but are considering an upgrade to 2k12).
2. Three of my parameters are long strings of Guid values separated by quotes and commas.  Basically the user is presented with a list of product lines, hundreds of them at times.  They then click the ones they want to search. We've limited the number of lines they can check just because the strings get too long, but we're passing a long string of Guids separated by quotes and commas.  I know this isn't the right way to do this.  What would be the standard Trans SQl pattern for passing in arrays or collections of Guid values like this?  I have 3 separate fields of the 40 doing this.  We want to do this more efficiently and also be able to pass in more than our current limitation.

Comment: A k to save two 0?   Pretty sure you can pass a TVP to a stored procedure.

Comment: Table valued params are SQL2008+

Comment: This links provide options prior to 2008 but non of them look all that attractive http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb675163(v=vs.90).aspx  Another reason for 2012.

Comment: I'd really like to use TVP but I'm afraid this project has a deliverable date well before the time it's going to take for us to test and migrate to 2k12.

Comment: How can a string be "too long"? You know that `varchar(max)` supports over two billion characters, right? That's a lot of GUIDs.

Comment: Also commenting on whether your 40 parameters would be more efficient as a table-valued parameter is tough - are they all the same data type? What kinds of things do they represent? It might be better but more specifics are necessary. I will recommend to you that passing in XML and then shredding it will NOT be more efficient than whatever you're doing now.

Answer (score 5):

## SQL Server 2005

Until you can take advantage of Table-Valued Parameters, I would suggest just creating a specialized table-valued UDF that splits up your GUID parameters. You could then use the output in a join, exists clause, cross apply, etc.

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.SplitGUIDs
(
   @List       VARCHAR(MAX),
   @Delimiter  VARCHAR(255)
)
RETURNS TABLE
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
   RETURN 
   (  
      SELECT [GUID] = CONVERT(UNIQUEIDENTIFIER, x) FROM
      ( 
        SELECT x = RTRIM(y.i.value('.[1]', 'nvarchar(4000)'))
        FROM 
        ( 
          SELECT x = CONVERT(XML, '<i>' 
            + REPLACE(@List, @Delimiter, '</i><i>') 
            + '</i>').query('.')
        ) AS a CROSS APPLY x.nodes('i') AS y(i)
      ) AS x WHERE LEN(x) > 0
   );
GO
```

Usage:

```
DECLARE @GUIDs VARCHAR(MAX);

SET @GUIDs = 'E2072E08-84D3-4EEA-A6ED-F38F1E4E34A6,'
           + 'A6B047BA-647E-4B35-8D95-F4A204B860F6';

SELECT [GUID] FROM dbo.SplitGUIDs(@GUIDs, ',') AS g;
```

Results:

```
Item
------------------------------------
E2072E08-84D3-4EEA-A6ED-F38F1E4E34A6
A6B047BA-647E-4B35-8D95-F4A204B860F6
```

The stored procedure might look like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.Whatever
  @GUIDs VARCHAR(MAX)
AS 
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;

  SELECT t.columns
    FROM dbo.sometable AS t
    INNER JOIN dbo.SplitGUIDs(@GUIDs, ',') AS g
    ON t.key = g.[GUID];
END
GO
```

(The function will fail, of course, if any of the elements in your string contain an invalid GUID. In SQL Server 2012 you could use `TRY_CONVERT()` but then you wouldn't need to because you'd be using TVPs, more below.)

## SQL Server 2008+

Later when you graduate from SQL Server 2005 (and for other readers who face this problem but are on SQL Server 2008+), you can do this much more efficiently using a table type:

```
CREATE TYPE dbo.GUIDs AS TABLE(GUID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER PRIMARY KEY);
```

Then your stored procedure can take this type as input instead of a big string:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.Whatever
  @GUIDs dbo.GUIDs READONLY
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;

  SELECT t.columns
    FROM dbo.sometable AS t
    INNER JOIN @GUIDs AS g
    ON t.key = g.[GUID];
END
GO
```

(Note how easy it will be to switch to TVPs - only lines 2 and 9 needed to change.)

Then your web app can pass a collection such as a DataTable to the @GUIDs parameter. No messy string splitting, no type conversions, no artificial limits on how many different GUIDs you can pass.

Comment: Your solution above is actually how we're doing it.  We're pass in the list of GUIDS as a giant string, then we pass that string into a UDF that returns a table filled with those Guids.  We then join that table to our main FROM statement in the sproc.

Comment: But we're doing this for 3 sets of values and 3 extra tables with tons of string manipulation.  I am trying to find away to optimize this.

Comment: So have `@GUIDs1, @GUIDs2, @GUIDs3`? Maybe you and I have different perceptions of "optimization" - if the rest of your query is complex, how you handle the GUIDs will not fix that.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me like you are trying to achieve too much with one stored procedure. 
I would try to break the search algorithm or query down into smaller peices and collate specific results for specific search entities into a result set.

Possible alternatives:

- Compose a SQL query dynamically within your application.
- Break your procedure down into multiple smaller procedures and only call the ones necessary based on the search criteria

Having to parse CSV (manually) in T-SQL is in my honest opinion a code/architecture smell in most instances.

Edit: Just read up... http://technet.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms187926(v=sql.90).aspx

> A stored procedure can have a maximum of 2,100 parameters.

So what's the problem? I assumed you were coming up against a limit for some reason.
Just use more parameters, it is infinitely preferable to parsing CSV. 
Also don't forget that you are able to supply default values for stored proc parameters so that you don't have to supply all 40+ parameters each time it is called providing they are sent named.

Also don't forget Table Valued UDFs... they're quite nice in that they can be used in the below fashion

```
select * from dbo.fn_ProductsByLine('Toasters') pbl inner join dbo.fn_ProductsByPrice(10,20) pbp on pbl.productID = pbp.productID
```

Comment: I've tried breaking it down into multiple queries and to an extent we have, but this is our largest one. Basically we have a catalog of products, from electronics to sporting goods to jewelery, etc.. There are tons of fields to search and we've limited to fields that are common to all.  But when you add them all up you can see that it's a big list of possibilities and not really easily reduced.

Comment: For example:  Price From, Price To, Margin Price From, margin Price To, text search of name/description, country of origin, country of manufacture, Is Closeout, Is Green, Is USA Only, Is Drop Shippable, Has Hi Res Image, date range from and to for product creation and product latest update dates, range of drop ship days, then a list each of lines, categories, and product IDs they want to search.

Comment: I do see your difficulty and I appreciate my answer would require changes outside the scope of the DB. Have you considered replacing the boolean fields with a bitmap?

Comment: The problem with using individual parameters for every GUID is that you have to make serious modifications to the interface to the procedure, the body itself, the data access layer, etc. if the business rule people decide that now you need to support 50, or 75, or 500 GUIDs. Joining to a split function would make converting to a TVP later much easier.